# Trying to build a php excerpt function

Tags: php, regex

I pull a bunch of content from a field on a database.

This content can be anything from the standard

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book.
```

to a much more complicated string involving html tags.

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
<a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a> has been the industry's <strong>standard</strong> 
dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a <b>galley</b> 
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

Now the easy way i first attempted was to simply use

```
substr($row['Description'],0,250);
```

however i quickly realized that it causes issues when the text get's cut-off in the middle of a tag, effectively bolding and/or linking everything after it.

I googled my butt off, but everything that comes up is a word-press addon/plugin. Which isnt very helpful.

So i need to build a function that will take into account

1. Character limit
2. check if limit ends within a tag, and extend the limit to close the tag.

So for instance, if the limit is 10:

```
<?php
$string="Hello this is a dummy text";
echo substr($string,0,10);
//output = "Hello this"

$string="Hello <b>this is a dummy</b> text";
//Better excerpt function
//output = "Hello this is a dummy"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have concocted this sad little function so far. I just know there's a cleaner way to do it. Also this function isn't ideal as it only takes into account the first tag it finds.
But at least it might get the point across better.

```
function eventExcerpt($text)
{
    #echo $text;

    $excerpt = substr($text, 0, 250);

    $opening_tags = array('<a', '<p', '<ul', '<li', '<b', '<strong', '<span', '<div');
    $closing_tags = array('</a>','</p>','</ul>','</li>','</b>','</strong>','</span>','</div>');

    $has_html = 0;

    foreach($opening_tags as $key => $val)
        {
            if(strpos($excerpt, $val))
                {
                    // Found an opening_tag within the excerpt
                    $has_html = $key;
                    break;
                }
        }


    if($has_html != "")
        {
            // echo text up until the closing_tag it found within excerpt but using text
            $closed_tag_pos = strpos($text, $closing_tags[$has_html]);
            echo substr($text, 0, $closed_tag_pos);
        }
    else
        {
            // echo excerpt since no opening_tags were found
            echo $excerpt;
        }
}
```

I should also mention, i'm running on PHP 5.2.5

Comment: wait... So the strings from the db already has the tags in them? And then from that string you want to display it on your page?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Do you want that the function takes into account the tags size. In other words, when you want 100 characters, do you count the size of, for example `<b>` and `</b>` *(in this case the result will be 100 characters long with 93 characters of plain text)* or not *(in this case the result will be 107 characters long with 100 characters of plain text)*?

Comment: Do not count the tag size, as once rendered as html it wont be visible text.

Comment: @ipixel why not use DOMDocument or similar tool instead? This way you can easily identify tags and deal with it and its content as you can also easily replace nodes.

Comment: @Prix, I've never used this before. Frankly didn't know of it's existence. I'll look into it thanks!

Comment: @ipixel it usually comes pre-installed with most versions of PHP(you can check it with `phpinfo()`) but if yours doesn't have it an alternative would be http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Tidy extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to do the job easily. Example:

```
$tidyText = new Tidy();
$options = array('indent' => true);

$text = substr($yourText, 0, 250) . '...';
$tidyText->parseString($text, $options);
$tidyText->cleanRepair();
echo $tidyText;
```

This will automatically repair unclosed/mis-matched tags after stripping is done so you get your excerpt right.

*Note: Make sure that Tidy extension is turned on from php.ini*

### Alternative without Tidy extension:

You can try and use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) also like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourText);
$clean = $dom->saveXML();
echo $clean;
```

Comment: Sadly i'm on PHP 5.2.5 and i cannot use Tidy. This would have been amazing though.

Comment: Sweet, that works wonderfully. I made 1 tiny change to account for the 250 limit but this works great! Thanks a ton @Sarfraz.